# Uninstall flash player debugger

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, debugging, animate-cc

I have installed the AIR flash debugger and now when I try testing my movie in flash it takes a long time to load, because of the debug mode, how can I uninstall it?

Downloaded the debugger from the official Adobe website.

Comment: To improve your question : Show a link to the file you installed. Did you install into CC by editing some config xml files pointing to any file paths? Did you replace any `FlashPlayer.exe` file in the Debugger sub-folder? Mention any useful details of what you did, for a faster Answer...

Comment: Edited the post :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want uninstall Flash Player debugger, you can't use the usually Windows control panel form but you must download Flash Player Uninstaller so you must run it.

You can see [here on the related Adobe help site](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html)

**EDIT**

Try this [link](http://www.windowsuninstaller.org/winuninstall/how-to-remove-adobe-edge-animate-cc-guide-adobe-edge-animate-cc-uninstaller-info.html) where you can find a smart guide about uninstall Adobe Animate CC and the uninstaller file.

Comment: Oh! didn't know that. will definitely try!

Comment: Sometimes It will say AIR20.0 is not installed when it is and sometimes It will do this

Comment: Can't get it to work. it uninstalls flash player only, not the debugger.

Comment: Try to uninstall the first the Adobe Animate CC and then the debugger

Comment: Tried uninstalling Animate CC, still the debugger is working.... Maybe I can delete the files of the debugger somehow? I use Windows

Comment: Plus I don't know where the files get stored, and it eats my C drive...

Comment: Sorry, I must link on your PC to check settings